# Geoserver - How can I make segmented roads appear as one line?

Tags: geoserver

I have shp file with segmented roads.
I've edited the SLD in geoserver and the final result looks like this :

[image]

How can I make the roads look continuous ?

This is the roads SLD I use :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>roads</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>roads</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>first</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>first</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>footway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>footpath</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>steps</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>cycleway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>pedestrian</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>track</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>residential</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>9000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>30000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#646450</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
              <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">11.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">11.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>

        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>second</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>second</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>footway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>footpath</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>steps</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>cycleway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>pedestrian</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>track</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>bridleway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>residential</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>30000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>150000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#c7c7c7</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>third</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>third</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>footway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>footpath</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>steps</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>cycleway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>pedestrian</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>track</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>bridleway</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>residential</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>2</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>9000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#505050</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f8f8f8</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>forth</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>forth</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>secondary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>tertiary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>20000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#505050</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f8f8f8</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>fifth</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>fifth</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>secondary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>tertiary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>20000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>200000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#505050</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>sixth</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>sixth</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary_link</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>trunk</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#505050</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffe168</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>eighth</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>eighth</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>motorway</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#4c2600</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#fa9e25</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.904762</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
         <se:Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
         </se:Label>
             <se:Font>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">David</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9.0</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-style">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Font>
         <se:LabelPlacement>
           <se:LinePlacement />
         </se:LabelPlacement>

         <se:VendorOption name="followLine">true</se:VendorOption>
       </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Please edit you question to include the SLD that you used. Cheers

Comment: How are you styling the layer? I usually use something similar to this: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#line-with-border I've never had issues with that.

Comment: @MarkC : Added SLD for lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Geoserver Docs have a simple and small [example available](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#line-with-border) , which states:

> Lines in SLD have no notion of a “fill”, only “stroke”. Thus, unlike points or polygons, it is not possible to style the “edge” of the line geometry. It is, however, possible to achieve this effect by drawing each line twice: once with a certain width and again with a slightly smaller width.

In SLD's if you want one thing to be drawn on top of another, you need to use multiple `<FeatureTypeStyle>` tags, each which defines a Feature type. The [Geoserver Documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/styles.html#featuretypestyle) states:

> each one is rendered into a separate image buffer. After all features are rendered the buffers are composited to form the final layer image.

Looking at your SLD, I can see that your SLD is structured like this:

```
FeatureTypeStyle
    --> Rule
        -->LineSymbolizer
        -->LineSymbolizer
    --> Rule
        -->LineSymbolizer
        -->LineSymbolizer
```

and so on.

You need to  edit your SLD, and have a structure somewhat like this:

```
FeatureTypeStyle
    --> Rule
        -->LineSymbolizer
FeatureTypeStyle
    --> Rule
        -->LineSymbolizer
FeatureTypeStyle
    --> Rule
        -->LineSymbolizer
FeatureTypeStyle
    --> Rule
        -->LineSymbolizer
```

I'm aware that will give rise to a lot of redundant information, like repeating the Filters and ScaleDenominators etc, but as far as I know, this is the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi Devdatta , Your solution didn't work.
I've added my SLD , please advise.

Comment: @Alophind: In your new SLD, I can't see where you are drawing the casing (i.e the Boundary).

Comment: What is casing / Boundary ?
Its SLD I took from QGIS and than added it to geoserver. What style am I missing here ?

Comment: If you want the boundary, You do it by having a thicker line behind the main symbol. See the [linked](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#line-with-border) SLD in my answer. the Thicker marker is partially covered by the smaller marker, and this gives you the appearance of casing, or boundary for the line.

Comment: Devdatta , My problem isn't boundary , my problem is that the roads doesn't look like continues roads , its hard to see from the image , but they look like line on line.. instead of 1 continues line

Answer (score 0):

@Devdatta Tengshe is Correct. The SLD uses feature type styles to determine the drawing order and draws them in the order that they appear in the SLD file. You need to move them out of one Feature Type Style into multiple Feature Type Styles.

However, have a look at the new [CSS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/index.html) Module (well not new, but it has now [graduated](http://geo-solutions.blogspot.com/2013/10/geoserver-css-module-graduated-to.html) to an official extension), if you are new to SLD, this will save you a lot of grief and a lot of coding.